# Jquery/Javascript Variable scope issue with $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm having issues with the following situation:

```
leeftijd:function(){
                var testvar = "untouched";

                var d = $('#gebdatumdd').val(),
                    m = $('#gebdatummm').val(),
                    y = $('#gebdatumjjjj').val();

                x = "none!";

                $.get("assets/incl/ageCheck.php", {y:y, m:m, d:d},
                    function(data){                 
                        console.log(data); // returns 'green';      
                        console.log(testvar);    // returns 'untouched';    
                        testvar = data; // write data in testvar;
                        console.log(testvar); // returns 'green';
                });

                console.log('outside: ' + testvar); // returns 'untouched'; 

            }
```

My 'testvar' just wont return the right value. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to understand the concept of callbacks in javascript and how it is used in jquery. Once you start the $.get() only thing you can be sure to run AFTER getting is the callback. You can call other stuff from there. The code in lines below $.get() is irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ajax call is async. So that last `console.log` is executed before the request has finished. You have to do all processing requiring the results of the request in the callback function.

Another option would be using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with the `async: false` option. However, this may lock up the browser until the request has finished!

Answer (score 1):

You could either run it synchronously. I think it should be possible to wrap your $.get() call with something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });

$.get();

$.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
```

A better solution would be to actually use the callback method to handle whatever you want to happen when the age check is done.

```
function ageCheckCallback(data) {
// Update form
}
```